# Why I get SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: the object does not have 'tax', in WSDL with nested complextype?

Tags: php, arrays, soap

I have to consume a SOAP web services with PHP and I get the title error.

The (partial) structure of the wsdl is it:

```
<xs:element name="Obligations" type="tns:ObligationsType"/>
<xs:complexType name="ObligationsType">
<xs:sequence>

<xs:element maxOccurs="99" name="Taxes" type="tns:TaxesType"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="TaxesType">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="tax">
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:int">
<xs:maxInclusive value="9999"/>
<xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="amount">
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:double">
<xs:minInclusive value="0.01"/>
<xs:maxInclusive value="9999999999.99"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The associative array that I send:

```
    $params = array(
            'token' => $TOKEN,
            'sign' => $SIGN,
            'paymentEntity' => 1001,
            'form' => array(
                'formNumber' => 6042,
                'idPaymentType' => 951,
                'Obligations' => array (
                                     array( 
                                         'Taxes' => array(
                                                        'tax' => 6041,
                                                        'amount' => 602.0 
                                                         )
                                           )
                                        )
                             )              
                );
```

I tried to do it with classes and I get the same error. The problem is from the Obligations object.

I tried nesting like this:

> 'Obligations' =>array ('Taxes' =>array('tax'=> 1,'amount'=> 1.0)) I get Unrecognized field Obligations
>
> 'Obligations' =>array ('tax'=> 1,'amount'=> 1.0) I get object has no 'Taxes' property
>
> 'Obligations' =>array (array('Taxes' =>array('tax'=> 1,'amount'=> 1.0))) I get object has no 'tax' property
>
> 'Obligations' =>array ('Taxes' =>array('tax'=> 1)) I get object has no 'amount' property
>
> 'Obligations' =>array ('Taxes' =>array('amount'=> 1)) I get object has no 'tax' property

The last request xml

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="...">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:createForm>
<ns1:token>********</ns1:token>
<ns1:sign>********</ns1:sign>
<ns1:paymentEntity>1001</ns1:paymentEntity>
<ns1:form>
    <ns1:formNumber>6042</ns1:formNumber>
    <ns1:idPaymentType>951</ns1:idPaymentType>
    <ns1:Obligations>
        <ns1:Taxes>
            <tax>6041</tax>
            <amount>602.0</amount>
        </ns1:Taxes>
    </ns1:Obligations>
</ns1:form>
</ns1:createForm>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The structure

```
"createFormResponse createForm(createForm $parameters)" [2]=> string(74)
"struct createForm { string token; string sign; int paymentEntity; FormType form; }" 
"struct FormType { formNumber formNumber; idPaymentType idPaymentType; Obligations ObligationsType; }"
"struct ObligationsType { TaxesType Taxes; }"
"struct TaxesType { tax tax; amount amount; }"
```

I have a request example and it is the same as the one I obtain.
It only has the note that

> Taxes tax. This attribute is list type.
>
> Taxes amount. This attribute is list type.

but it is something that is already marked in the wsdl.

I would appreciate any suggestions. regards

Answer (score 0):

it 's better to work with objects when dealing with complex types. It 's cleaner and easier to handle. The following example is a hint how to deal with complex types using php.

```
/**
 * Entity from complex type ObligationsType
 * @see xsd:complexType "ObligationsType"
 */ 
class ObligationsType
{
    /**
     * Is an array because the containing 'TaxtesType' can appear up to 99 times
     * @var \ArrayObject
     */
    protected $Taxes;

    public function getTaxes() : \ArrayObject
    {
        return $this->Taxes;
    }

    public function setTaxes(TaxesType $taxes) : ObligationsType
    {
        if ($this->Taxes === null) {
            $this->Taxes = new \ArrayObject();
        }

        $this->Taxes->append($taxes);
        return $this;
    }

    public function encode() :\SoapVar
    {
        $container = new \ArrayObject();
        foreach (get_obect_vars($this) as $property) {
            if ($property instanceof \ArrayObject) {
                foreach ($property as $element) {
                    $container->append($element);
                }
            } else {
                $container->append($property);
            }
        }

        return new \SoapVar(
            $container, 
            SOAP_ENC_OBJ, 
            null, 
            null, 
            'Obligations',
            'http://www.example.com/namespace/tns'
        );
    }
}

class TaxesType
{
    protected $tax;

    protected $amount;

    public function getTax() : int
    {
        return $this->tax;
    }

    public function setTax(int $tax) : TaxesType
    {
        $this->tax = $tax;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getAmount() : float
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }

    public function setAmount(float $amount) : TaxesType
    {
        $this->amount = $amount;
        return $this;
    }

    public function encode() : \SoapVar
    {
        return new \SoapVar(
            $this,
            SOAP_ENC_OBJ,
            null,
            null,
            'Taxes',
            'http://www.example.com/namespace/tns'
        );
    }
}
```

So now we got the two complex types described in your wsdl als PHP entity classes. The only thing this classes do is holding our data and encoding it for sending the data via the soap client class.

**How to use this?**

Just tell your soap client class, that you have classes for the expected data. The soap client has the option `classmap` for this purpose.

```
$client = new \SoapClient(
    $path_to_your_wsdl,
    [
        'class_map' => [
            'ObligationsType' => ObligationsType::class,
            'TaxesType' => TaxesType::class,
        ],
        'exceptions' => true,
        'trace' => true,
    ],
);

$tax1 = (new TaxesType())
    ->setTax(19)
    ->setAmount(49.99)
    ->encode();

$tax2 = (new TaxesType())
    ->setTax(7)
    ->setAmount(29.49)
    ->encode();

$obligations = (new ObligationsType())
    ->setTaxes($tax1)
    ->setTaxes($tax2)
    ->encode();

$result = $client->YourWebserviceFunction($obligations);
```

This simple code snipped should explain how xsd complex types work with the php soap client. Figuratively every complex type is a class with members that are described for the complex type. This understanding makes it easy to handle data within soap requests and responses. Furthermore every webservice function has a return type described in the wsdl or any bound xsd file. Find this return type and make a php class out of it and mention it in the classmap option of the soap client. The soap client can easily hydrate the return of a request in the return type class, which is mentioned in the classmap option.

As you can see, SOAP and PHP work pretty well together.

Always remember: The code shown above is not tested. Please do not use this code in production.

**Edit: How to get the last request in a try/catch block**

As you mentioned in the comments under this answer, you can 't get the last request. I 'll show you in the next lines, how you can do it. Just wrap the soap client init in a try catch block. If the soap client is initialized, it is accessible in the catch block, too.

```
try {
    $client = new \SoapClient(
        $wsdl_path,
        $options
    );

    // call of your webservice methods here
    ...

} catch (\SoapFault $e) {
    // get the last request in the catch block
    if ($client !== null) {
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump(htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest()));
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

Don 't forget to set the trace option to true. If not you can 't call the `__getLastRequest()` method of the soap client.

Please edit your question with the last xml request.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this way but I still get the same error

Comment: Can you post an XML example of the last request you sent? You can get the last request with `$client->__getLastRequest()` when you created the soap client with the trace option. Just add your last request to your question above.

Comment: I know the command, but can not show the request because I get **Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Server.userException] com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Obligations"**

Comment: I 've edited my answer and added an example, how to get the last request in a catch block. Please follow the shown code and edit your question with the last request xml.

Comment: I added the last request xml.

Comment: The token and sign data are not real

Comment: Looks fine for me. The next step you can make: Have a look for the webservice function `createForm` with `$client->__getFunctions()` and then have a look which types are in need for this function (parameter type) via `$client->__getTypes()`. Do you have an request example, how it should look like?

Comment: I added the structure

Comment: Great! As you can see the `createForm` struct, that you need for your request, has 4 properties called `token`, `sign`, `paymentEntity` and `form`. The fourth property `form` is missing in your request. Please have a look at the `FormType` struct. This struct contains a property called `Obligations`. As I said in my answer it 's easer to work with php classes when using complex types in a soap webservice. Now you know the structs. Just create classes out of them and then follow my example again. I 'm sure you can do it. ;)

Comment: thanks, but I do not understand. Did you see my last request? the structure is correct

Comment: Oh, my fault. Haven 't seen the form tag. Okay, so if you go alone according to the specifications of the web service, your request is formulated correctly. There is no error in the request. What about contacting the provider of this webservice?

Comment: Unfortunately, the provider does not answer questions and his documentation is poor.
I was looking for the solution on the side of:          

|      'Obligations' =>array ('Taxes' =>array('tax'=> 1,'amount'=> 1 ))  Encoding: object has no 'Obligations' property 

|      'Obligations' =>array ('Taxes' =>array('tax'=> 1)) I get object has no 'amount' property

 |      'Obligations' =>array ('Taxes' =>array('amount'=> 1)) I get object has no 'tax' property

Comment: This problem is solved with the above shown solution. You have to deliver always `tax` and `amount`. The taxes struct can occur up to max 9999 times in the `Obligations` property of the `FormType` struct. Just build up your request strictly with the given structs as php objects. In addition one should pay attention to the used namespaces in the wsdl file. If this does not help, use another webservice from a provider, who delivers a kind of support.

Comment: Does this provider not even provide exemplary requests?

Comment: The provider provide exemplary request and it's same that I generated